# How do I format the labels in an ASP.NET piechart so that they are outside chart in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am using asp.net with C# to make a pie chart the code is

```
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.Series["PTseries"].Points.AddXY(PS.Name, PS.Value);
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.Series["PTseries"].SetCustomProperty("PieLabelStyle", "outside");
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.Series["PTseries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;// Set the Pie width
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.Series["PTseries"]["PointWidth"] = "0.5";// Show data points labels
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.Series["PTseries"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";// Show chart as 3D
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;// Draw chart as 3D
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.Series["PTseries"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
```

This creates a pie chart that is labelled like this [image]

But I want it to look like this [image]

I only want the labels changed, the appearance of the actual chart doesnt matter.

Answer (score 1):

I just added this in the ascx code, not in the code behind

```
<Legends>
    <asp:Legend BackColor="Transparent" Alignment="Center" Docking="Right" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"
    IsTextAutoFit="true" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Column">
    </asp:Legend>
    </Legends>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Rotation = 5;
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Inclination = 60;
ProjectsByProjectTypePieChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.IsRightAngleAxes = false;
```

Try Setting the Above Properties it will Work